# How do you debug TS with ts-node and Chrome?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, debugging, ts-node

Script:

```
(async () => {
  debugger;
  const go = await showWarning();
  if (go) {
    const startTime = process.hrtime.bigint();
  // more code here
  }  
})();
```

command line:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect-brk npx ts-node --transpileOnly  \ 
testing/perf/src/run.ts
```

TSconfig:

```
{
    "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Process:

1. open Chrome inspect tab
2. kick off script from command line
3. inspector pauses, as it should
4. place breakpoint on line under `debugger`,  hit "Resume" button
5. script runs, completely misses the `debugger` line and the breakpoint

Chrome has access to the script file and loads it. I can see the script in the debugger, but it's never stopping there. There's probably something wrong with my TSconfig, but I don't know what. All the answers to this that I have found are for IDE debuggers, which I don't want to use (if you really want to know I'll tell you but it seems off-topic).